# Extract the coefficients of formal Laurent series in characteristic $p$

Tags: derivatives, finite-fields, laurent-series, formal-power-series, positive-characteristic

Let $f=\sum_{i=0}^\infty f_i T^i\in \mathbb{F}[[T]]$ be a formal power series over a field $\mathbb{F}$ of characteristic $p$. For every $k\geq 0$, we define the $k$-th Hasse derivative on $\mathbb{F}[[T]]$:
$$\partial_T^{[k]}\colon f\longmapsto \sum_{i=0}^\infty f_i\binom{i}{k}T^{i-k}.$$
Then an easy observation is that we can extract the coefficients with the Hasse derivation: $\left(\partial_T^{[k]}f\right)(0)=f_k$. And this gives a Taylor expansion formula for formal power series over field of positive characteristic. Evenmore, we can generalize this to the multivariable case.

---

Now my question is that, can we extract the coefficients of formal Laurent series $g=\sum_{i>\!>-\infty}g_i T^i\in\mathbb{F}((T))$ by using a similar operator? If we replace $\mathbb{F}$ with $\mathbb{C}$, then the Cauchy integrate formula may give what we want. However there is no such thing in characteristic $p$.